# Which Symfony2 version do I use? 2.2 or 2.3?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.2

I'm just starting out with Symfony2 and looking to create medium-sized site. I've been learning it over the last two months.

I currently have 2.2 installed.

The question is: should I create the site now with 2.2 or ditch that and go with 2.3, even though it's not fully released.

I expect this site to be used for many years so I think the 2.3 LTS version is better, but of course it's not fully released.

I'm not bothered about the odd extra feature in a minor release, but it's the fact that 2.3 is a long term release (3 years) or something that I'm interested in. Does it seem crazy to code  a site now in 2.2? Apparently 2.2 is supported for 8 months?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need stable `right now` and the site is mall enough to be fully functional before 2.3 will reach some level of maturity then you should go with 2.2, otherwise 2.3 is the right pick, the fact that is a LTS gives enough support to a long term project.

Symfony 2.2

- need stable code `right now`
- site is small enough to be fully functional before 2.3 is mature
- you don't mind about security updates past those 8 months

Symfony 2.3

- LTS, support for long term projects, 3 years
- lots of developers will master this version, lots of helpers in forums, irc, etc

So in brief, the reasons to use 2.2 right now are very specific, if time is not and issue I would use 2.3 beta and keep upgrading till the official release.

Quoting Potencier: `Symfony2 LTS release, will be released at the end of May 2013`